# Corona SDK zoom in/out to area like angry brid

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I zoom in/out to a specific area like angry bird game when the player want to explore the whole playground.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can zoom in/out by change the xScale and yScale of the image.

for example:

if you want to zoom in 2 times to the middle:

```
backG = display.newImageRect("backG.png", 320, 568)
backG.x = display.contentCenterX 
backG.y = display.contentCenterY 

function zoomIn()
    backG.xScale = 2  
    backG.yScale = 2
end
function zoomOut()
    backG.xScale = 1  
    backG.yScale = 1
end
zoomIn() -- call this when the event happens
```

if you want to zoom in to other place in the back ground, you have to change to xScale, yScale as well as the x and y.

```
backG.xScale = 2  
backG.yScale = 2
backG.x = backG.x - 100
```

this will zoom in to the left part.
If your playground has more than 1 object, you can put them in a group and change the xScale, yScale, x, y of that group.

```
group1 = display.newGroup()
group1:insert(backG)
group1:insert(otherObject)

group1.xScale = 2 -- now you can change the group's x y or scale same as an object.
```

Also you may need to find out which part user want to zoom in to, 
this cloud be done by record the x, y of tap event, or allow user to drag the playground after the zoom in.